# How to enable group replication again after dissolving a MySQL Innodb Cluster using mysqlsh?

Tags: mysql

When I dissolve a innodb cluster using mysqlsh it automatically disables replication on the instance.

How do I enable replication on the instance again so i can "start group replication" after a cluster dissolve? I'm getting these errors in the log after I dissolve a cluster and try to start group replication again. my group replication was working fine before the dissolve.

[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Invalid hostname or IP address () assigned to the parameter local_node!'

[ERROR] [MY-011674] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Unable to initialize the group communication engine'

[ERROR] [MY-011637] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Error on group communication engine initialization'

[ERROR] [MY-011718] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Error calling group communication interfaces while trying to leave the group'

Answer (score 0):

creating a new innodb cluster and adding the instances will start the group replication again on those instances but I'm still unable to find how I can enable group replication manually with "start group replication" sql command without a cluster